# Php function returning associate array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I would like to know how to make a function return an associative array. I am getting only values of the returned array but not keys

Comment: This question needs context, can you show some code please?

Comment: [`function ReturnsAssocArray() { return array('key' => 'value'); }`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/j2Sa6M) O.o

Comment: is it returned from a database? what's going on with that function?

Answer (score 6):

you need to set those keys yourself like. If not it adds automatically an index starting from 0. Have a look at my example

```
function myfunc(){
    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = 'value0';
    $arr['key1'] = 'value1';
    $arr['key2'] = 'value2';
    $arr[] = 'value3';
    return $arr;
}
```

that will output

```
// you see the first and fourth value has the index 0 and 1, 
// the other those that are defined
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "value0"
  ["key1"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "value3"
}
```

http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Comment: if an array is giving values definitely it has keys; by deafult it adds 0,1 so on. like $arr[0]=>'matt' $arr[1]=>'swap'.

Comment: I got the answer it was some simple mistakes thanks everyone

Comment: ok if you have another problem with index, show us some code